# How to show the path to the current opened file?

Tags: command-line, statusline, path

If I open a file in vi like:

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Then vi shows in the bottom left corner of the window:

```
"/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" 1009L, 34418C
```

But when I edit the file with a or i then this line disappears.
And even when pressing Esc to exit the editing mode it wont come back.

How do I get this line back after editing?

Comment: I use `Ctrl+g` for this

Comment: Which is the same as `:file` :-) I wanted to give that as an answer, but is doesn't show the amount of characers. I'm not sure how to get *exactly* that line...

Comment: You can display this information in your statusline with `let &statusline = '"%f" %{line("$")}L, %{line2byte(line("$"))}C'`. You can also make a mapping to echo this: `nnoremap <Leader>fi :echo '"' . expand("%") . '" ' . line("$") . "L, " . line2byte(line("$")) . "C"<CR>`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think it shows bytes, not characters, despite the "C". I haven't looked carefully but for me the number seems to agree with output from `wc -c`, not from `wc -m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you save, you can then use `:e` again, to display *that* information. Also, you can use `g Ctrl-g` and/or `Ctrl-g` at any time to find out some (or the other) of the original info.

Comment: Mnemonic: `Ctrl-g` to find out what is **G**oing on.